# Trying to get property of non-object when trying to get ID in Laravel

Tags: laravel, if-statement, while-loop

I want to make leave application, where the boss can accept or reject leave request

My table in database like this

```
id |    name     |      email           | person_in_charge |
1      Michael        michael.com                2
2      Johan          johan.com                  4
3      Lorem          lorem.com                  2
4      Ipsum          ipsum.com                  5
5      Dolor          dolor.com
```

I want to, if user id 5 login, he can view all the request. If user id 2 login, he can view leave request from user id 1 and 3. If user id 4 login, he can view leave request from user id 2, user id 1 and user id 3.

I've doing using while looping, but I have error message "Trying to get property of non-object "

Here's the code

```
    $id='5';

    $query= Users::where('id',$id)->first();

    if($query->pic_for==null)
    {
        $query = Users::where('pic_for',$id)->first();
        $pic_for = $query->id;

        $pic=array($query->id);
        while($pic_for!=null)
        {
            $query2 = Users::where('pic_for',$pic_for)->first();
            //dd($query2);
            if($query2->pic_for==null)
            {
                break;
            }else
            {
                $pic[]=$query2->id;
                $pic_for = $query2->id;
            }

        }
        dd($pic);
    }
```

Do you know where I missed ?

Thank you

Comment: On what line are you recieving the error? Both `$query` and `$query2` can be `null`, you are not checking it so the error is there.

Comment: Hi @namelivia, when I tried daydump after while process, I got only 2 array results, it must be 4 array result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try that :

```
// prepare an empty $result collection that will store the ids of the users
$result = collect();

// probably a number, not a string, in your database: we should keep the right type
$id = 5;
addRelatedUsersToResult($id, &$result);

dd($result);

// add all the related users ids to the result 
// and call itself for each realted user (to check their relations)
function addRelatedUsersToResult($id, &$result) {
    $relatedUsers = Users::where('pic_for', $id)->get();

    // add the related users and checks their children
    foreach ($relatedUsers as $relatedUser) {
        $result->push($relatedUser->id);
        addRelatedUsersToResult($relatedUser->id, $result);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Hi @Florian Laforge, thank you, it works, but can you explain about the function addRelatedUsersToResult()

Comment: Hi, glad it helped you ! This is a recursive function : it means the function can call itself (like a cascade of function calls). The function adds all the direct related users of the user in parameter, and then calls itself for each related user (to add their related users) and so on. Be careful if you have a circular dependecy between your users, it would never end (infinite calls loop). A better way to understand this is to take a piece of paper and draw a tree of related user (with only one at the top) and simulate a call of the function on this one (the "chief"). Is it clearer ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$user = Users::find(5); //get the inital user
$picFor = $user->pic_for; //get its pointer
$pictures = []; //initialize the result array
while (!is_null($user) && !is_null($picFor)) { //if I have a valid user and pointer
  $user = Users::find($picFor); //get the user for the pointer
  if ($user !== null) { //if I have a valid user
    $picFor = $user->pic_for; //get the next pointer
    $pictures[]= $user->id; //add the user id to the result array
  }   
}
```

The main problem you are having is that you are missing some null checks.

Comment: Hi @namelivia, I have tried it, but it show null array when I tried daydump